# How to create a word docx using python docx in other than english?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am building a program creating printed outputs from python code.  Further, the final print containing the other language (Sinhala). I want to use python docx to save this output into a word document. How to write into word in another language?

My aim is to produce a report making program from another language (Sinhala). I take all user inputs from widgets and managed to print the resulted lines in another language in python. 
Now, I want to write these lines into word file using the Sinhala language.

```
a= "කණ්ඩියේ උස මීටර් 5.0 ක් පළල මීටර් 2.0 හා දිග මීටර් 2.0 ක් පමණ වන කොටසක් 
අස්ථාවර වී"


document = Document()
document.add_heading("python word doc")
document.add_paragraph(a)

document.save('****\\report.docx')
```

when I use English, the code does the job. But, for the Sinhala language, I'm not sure how to do that?
I get the following error message for sinala language.

ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

Answer (score 0):

The error code you're seeing is not directly related to the language. The only thing Word knows about language is which spelling dictionary to use. Otherwise its text is just an arbitrary sequence of unicode characters.

What I suspect is that the Unicode encoding of the Sinhala strings you're trying to write is not UTF-8. The other possibility is that the string contains some control characters (as mentioned in the error message), particularly the vertical-tab (VT, 0xB or decimal 11) which can arise in copy and paste from PowerPoint.

This latter one is easier to check for, so perhaps start there.

```
import re

def sanitize_str(s):
    control_chars = "\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f"
    control_char_re = re.compile("[%s]" % control_chars)
    return control_char_re.sub("", s)

document.add_paragraph(sanitize_str(a))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please accept the answer if it answered your question. That's how StackOverflow works :)